# create many AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer (IOS Camera) from same AVCaptureSession and adding them to same layer

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, avcapturesession

I created three AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayers from same AVCaptureSession and added them to the view's layer but what happens is the last one only i created appears

I want all of the appears , how?!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing it is possible in an easy way.

You can use this [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) library, but it works differently than AVFoundation. There you can create multiple `GPUImageView`s and they should display the image from capture session in realtime. Keep in mind, that it may reduce performance.